# Why can there be no reductions from NP-complete problems to P problems under P ≠ NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np, p-vs-np

Under the assumption that $P \ne NP$, why is it impossible to reduce a problem that is known to be NP-complete to a problem that is known to be of polynomial time complexity? What kind of fundamental theorems would this contradict if it was possible?

Comment: The definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would contradict the assumption that **P$\,\neq\,$NP**. You could solve the **NP**-complete problem in polynomial time by reducing it to a problem in **P** and solving that.

Comment: That is very true and a great, concise explanation. Thank you David!

Answer (score 2):

*This answer was a response to the [original version](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/73844/revisions) of the question, which has now been edited to ask something different.*

Contrary to your premise, it is possible. If $\text{P} \ne \text{NP}$, then *any* language in $\text{P}$ reduces to an $\text{NP}$-complete problem, but is not $\text{NP}$-complete itself.

In fact we don't need the $\text{P} \ne \text{NP}$ assumption. $\varnothing$ is not $\text{NP}$-complete but reduces easily to $\text{3-SAT}$.

Additional note: it is generally believed that [NP-intermediate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate) problems exist (this is equivalent to $\text{P} \ne \text{NP}$). These problems are not in $\text{P}$ and not $\text{NP}$-complete, but they reduce to $\text{NP}$-complete problems.

Comment: Realized now that I miswrote, ment to say from NP-complete to non-NP-complete.. Silly me. Great answer though, made me understand it a lot better! Thank you :)

Comment: Note that even with the original phrasing of the question, it is not necessarily possible to reduce a non-**NP**-complete problem to an **NP**-complete one. For example, the halting problem is not **NP**-complete but cannot be reduced to 3-SAT.  (Or, if you prefer something decidable, the same holds, unconditionally, for any **NEXP**-complete problem.)